# Spyder doesn't show matrices in the variable explorer

Tags: python, matrix, spyder

I'm new in Python and also in Spyder, so please forgive my silly questions.

I want to see all the variables, matrices and arrays in the variable explorer. It shows me everything except the matrices.
For example if I run `a = array([1,2,3,4])`, then I see it as expected in the variable explorer.
After I run `b = mat(a)` or `b = asmatrix (a)`, I cannot see b in the variable explorer. However the b is stored and

```
>>> b
matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

In the Spyder documentation I didn't find anything to expect matrices not to appear there. Must the matrices show up in the variable explorer or not? And if yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) The problem is quite simple: Spyder doesn't have support to show all types of objects in its Variable Explorer. We only support lists, dictionaries, `numpy` arrays, numbers and strings, if I remember correctly. You have discovered one important type (i.e. matrices), others are Pandas `DataFrames` and `Series`, which we should really add.

**Edit**: Numpy matrices, along with Pandas `DataFrames` and `Series` are shown and can be edited through the Variable Explorer since version `2.3.1`.

Comment: Thanks @Carlos!
Shall do smth to support the 2 bug reports you've opened?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If you know restructured text (i.e. how to write rst files) you could help us to improve our documentation so that other people can easily find the answer to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to write rst files, but I guess adding one sentence about the supported types is sufficient till your next release.

Comment: You're right, I'll do it for our next bugfix release (i.e. 2.2.5) to be released this weekend.

Comment: Ok, I just update our docs to mention this info. See [here](http://pythonhosted.org/spyder/variableexplorer.html#supported-types)

Comment: It's just fine @Carlos, this is enough. Thanks!

Comment: Matrices will be working with our next version (`2.3.1`). Enjoy!